# Put parameters. Where should I put them?

Tags: web-services, rest, web

In a RESTful way, should I pass PUT parameters as query strings (/users?param1=value1) or should I encode it as it was a POST request (/users)

Thanks!

Comment: You can send do this way too, but its better to send tin the request body.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a design , but let me say what REST principles say :

```
Resource
Unique URI
State Representation
```

Identify a resource here. which I can see is users. Now, Are parameters `param1,param2` etc represent any state of resource `users`? 
IF yes , Then they should be passed as request xml or json, whatever you are using. cause they represent the state
If no, then they can be used as query parameters, as they are acting as just filtering parameters. cause they are not represting any state of resource.